# Relationship between ReceivedRemoteNotification and DidReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.ios, remote-notifications

Would you believe it, not a single result when I search for this. The Xamarin APIs on developer.xamarin don't mention any relationship between the two either.

And to make things even more complicated, developer.apple says `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` is deprecated but there's no mention of this deprecation on developer.xamarin. Moreover, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-ios-get-started-push guides you on using it.

So now there's `WillPresentNotification` in the mix as well.

Can someone please shed some light on these? Specifically, how they are related, and which one to use when.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend reading up on the new design pattern apple has post iOS 10+ for [User Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter)

The old days remote notifications were always handled by the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol/interface and since your `AppDelegate` class defaults to implement that protocol it was common practice to handle incoming remote notifications from there with the now not used as much

`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` .

In iOS 10+, Apple abstracted notifications into the             `UNUserNotificationCenter` framework
and in order to assign the delegate you must assign the             `UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate` to either a custom class that sublcasses from `UserNotificationCenterDelegate` or, like me, make your `AppDelegate` implement the interface and handle things there.

Here is how I would implement things in `Xamarin.iOS`:

```
using Foundation
using UIKit;
using UserNotifications;

    public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate, IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    {
        public override UIWindow Window { get; set; }

        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;
            return true;
        }

        [Export("userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:")]
        public void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, System.Action completionHandler)
        {
            //Handle Notification if user interacts with notification in Notification Center of iOS.
        }

        [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
        public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, System.Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
        {
            //Handle Notification if app is in the foreground when recieved.
        }
    }
```

Of course you will want to look at the [User Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter) framework to see how to implement classes such as `UNNotification` and `UNNotification` response if you are not familiar with those classes.

Comment: Thanks @NSGangster. How does `ReceivedRemoteNotification` fit into all this?

Comment: It's deprecated. Don't use it unless you are supporting versions previous to iOS 10.0

Comment: Ok I just noticed where the deprecation is noted. It's in the Syntax example on this page: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplicationDelegate.ReceivedRemoteNotification/p/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary/. I was looking for a _Deprecated_ sign in big noticeable red font on that page, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` is NOT deprecated. It's still required to handle background notifications (the ones that wake up your app to do stuff in the background).

UNUserNotificationCenter mostly deals with UI-related notifications or actions, but still cannot handle background notification.

Comment: This is correct. I misused the word deprecated in my post. I meant the usual method of receiving notification related data had changed.